# Issue with use of subtr() function

Tags: javascript, substr

I am working on a hangman game project and am having trouble with replacing a specific blank with the correctly guessed letter. The bolded function replaceAt() is where I'm having trouble. If the word is 'potato' and the user has a guessed the letter 'a' the word is turned into 6 blanks. The index of the guess is i or 3. Yet the last line of code logs : _ _ a _ _ _ _

Why is a in the wrong position? I also realize there is an extra blanks added to the end as well.

```
   var domStrings = {
  word : document.querySelector('#word'),
  guess : document.querySelector('#guess')
}



var gameController = function(){
  //1. create number of dashes according to input.length
  setup();
  //2. create function where if input includes guess the dash turns to that letter
  checker();
  //3. else turn counter runs down

}


var setup = function (){
  var dashes,
  dashes = '_ '.repeat(input.length);
  word.textContent = dashes;
}


var checker = function(){
  var arr, rightGuess, blanks;
  submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    blanks = String(word.textContent);
    if(input.includes(guess.value)){
      //1. convert str to array
      console.log('this is a correct guess');
      arr = (input.split(''));
      //2. for each element in array compare to guess
      for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        if(guess.value === arr[i]){
          replaceAt(blanks, i, domStrings.guess.value);

**var replaceAt = function (blanks, i, letter){

      console.log(`${blanks.substr(0, i)} ${letter} ${blanks.substr(i+1)}`);**
```

Comment: `word.textContent` has spaces in it. I don't believe you are accounting for them. Try `console.log(\`${dashes.substr(0, i*2)} ${letter} ${dashes.substr(i*2+1)}\`);`

Comment: instead of splitting to an array u could do guess.value === input[i]

Comment: Personally I would just have an array with what to display and not worry about string. `var display = ['_','o','o','_','_','r']; display[4] = 'a'; console.log(display.join(' '));`